# Use of @keyword in C# -- bad idea?

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions, keyword

In my naming convention, I use _name for private member variables. I noticed that if I auto-generate a constructor with ReSharper, if the member is a keyword, it will generate an escaped keyword. For example:

```
class IntrinsicFunctionCall
{
    private Parameter[] _params;
    public IntrinsicFunctionCall(Parameter[] @params)
    {
        _params = @params;
    }
}
```

Is this generally considered bad practice or is it OK? It happens quite frequently with @params and @interface.

EDIT: This doesn't actually add a prefix to the variable name. If accessing that variable from a different .NET language, i.e. F#, it would just be `params`. In fact, in C#, if you write `@x` it's exactly equivalent to `x`.

Comment: I'd leave the language keywords alone (just to be safe and less confusing). Easier for anyone to read my code.. they don't have to go look at what @ does when prefixed in front of a param name. It kind of stands out in that code block up there.. maybe its the highlighting.

Comment: rename your variables to `parameters`, and specify what the interface is when using it rather than just `interface`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using language keywords as identifiers impacts the readability. Granted, proper syntax high-lightning helps a bit, but it's better to not rely on the editor features only.

Consider the following (exaggeratedly unreadable, obviously :-)) code:

```
interface IInterfaceFactory<T>
{
   T CreateInstance(params object[] @params);
}

class SomeClass
{
    IMyOtherInterface _interface;

    public IMyOtherInterface Interface
    {
        get { return _interface; }
    }

    public SomeClass(params object[] @params)
    {
        SomeInterface<IMyOtherInterface> interfaceFactory = new SomeInterface<IMyOtherInterface>();
        IMyOtherInterface @interface = interfaceFactory.CreateInstance(@params);
        if (@interface->IsValid())
        {
            _interface = @interface;
        }
        else
        {
            _interface = interfaceFactory.CreateInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not generally bad practise. If you prefer to use prefixes for some kind of variables, it's ok. As far as I know, Microsoft recommends not to use prefixes, besides the I on interface names.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on your personal taste, however you need to keep your style consistent for all of your code.

This is sample of code consistency, use same style along the way.

```
int @number;
string @name;
```

This may consider a bad code, use mix style.

```
int @number;
string _name;
```

Comment: @ doesn't actually add a prefix. If you had a variable @number, just "number" would refer to the same variable.

Comment: I see you point @Robert but my answer is concentrate on coding style and readability of source code. :)